# How would you programmatically determine which UITableViewRow is displayed?

Tags: uitableview

Scenario:

1. A member UITableView within a UIViewController
2. A 2nd member MKMapView above that, sharing the same UIViewController.

Each row of the UITableView contains an image that I want to display as a MKMapView annotation.

[image]

**Question:** how do I determine which row is displayed (say, at the top of the UITableView)?

Once I have the particular row, I can extract the image/row & display it as an annotation.

Comment: You shouldn't be looking to mine the table view for info, you should be going back to your source data. Have you looked at the methods the table view offers about what's currently visible?

Comment: I've checked both the UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource.  The closest methods are: 'willDisplayCell' and 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'.  I would rather choose one (1) cell at the top of the viewing area vs flashing each cell's attribute as it becomes visible.

Comment: Paradigm change: I'm going to make this simpler - merely display the cell's attribute/selection by the user.

Answer (score 0):

A table view is a kind of scroll view, so you can use the scroll view delegate methods (called automatically on the table view delegate) to know when the visible rows change. Then you can call `indexPathsForVisibleRows:` on the table view to find out what's visible.

Then you should use those index paths to get the image data from your data source.